# Closures with objects

Tags: javascript, closures

I was reading about closures and i came across with this example:

```
  var counter = (function() {
  var privateCounter = 0;
  function changeBy(val) {
    privateCounter += val;
  }

  return {
    increment: function() {
      changeBy(1);
    }
  };
})();
```

So basically a closure is :

> A closure is the combination of a function bundled together (enclosed)
>   with references to its surrounding state (the lexical environment).

Ok so far so good. But in following example, we dont have functions bundled together but the returned object keeps a ref to  privateCounter.

Can we consider this also some sort of closure?

```
var counter = (function() {
  var privateCounter = { name: "nick" };

  return {
    name: privateCounter
  };
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The function does not access variables from it's outer scope.

Comment: Forget about the function. Im talking about the returned object which holds a ref to the variable

Comment: "In programming languages, a closure, also lexical closure or function closure, is a technique for implementing lexically scoped name binding in a language with first-class functions. Operationally, a closure is a record storing a **function** [a] together with an environment.[1]" ~ Wikipedia